# What does "import <XYZ/XYZ.h>" mean

Tags: objective-c, import

I am new to objective-c and started iphone application development. I have noticed the import statement like `import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` etc... I wanted to know what does it mean. Why not simply `import <UIKit>` or `import <UIKit.h>`? In fact if I do that, it gives a no-such-file-error"!

So does it mean that we should name our files like that? So that when we import the header, it looks like `MyApplication/MyApplication.h`? Or is it just for the libraries? Even if it is, then why is that so?

This syntax looks weird to me, so I am just asking out of curiosity. But may be I am supposed to use them somewhere that I am not doing. I guess knowing is the best solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIKit/UIKit.h` is a path. `UIKit` is some package and `UIKit.h` is the header that you are actually importing.

This is common for large frameworks and libraries in Objective-C, C, and C++.

Comment: UIKit is not a package, it is a **framework**. This is not Java or C#, you know.

Comment: @Radek I know that very well. I don't use Java or C#. Package, framework -- just different names for the same thing. Frameworks is just a fancy Apple term for packages. No need to get mad

Comment: Ahh right. Expanded the framework in xcode and saw those files. I have used Java and it uses "import abc.xyz.*" kind of syntax too. Just this / notation confused me :) .

Comment: @Sailesh no problem, there are always stumbling blocks when learning a new language :)

Answer (score 2):

This is just a convention for **frameworks** - the parent directory has the same name as the header file. You don't need to do this for headers which are not part of frameworks.